# Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString upload to dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
NSURL *kittenFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:img withExtension:nil];
}
```

This is my code. The warning i'm getting it Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *' When I go to collect the url of the user image to upload to dropbox, it crashes the app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`URLForResource:` is expecting a string whereas you are passing an image. That is the error. You need to pass a string there.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:stringPath withExtension:nil];
```

Not sure what you were planning to do with that, but `URLForResource:` param is expecting a path or file name and not a `UIImage`. For more details [check the apple documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:)

Just a guess, do you want to get the media url for that image. In that case you need to do like this,

```
NSURL *kittenFileURL = [editInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

The [available keys are listed here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys). For referenceURL you can use, `[editInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]`

On a side note,  `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is deprecated and you should be using `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`.